# Building OpenCV using makefile throwing error?

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake, compiler-errors

I was trying to setup OpenCV environment using MingW64 and visual studio code,

**Work done so far**

- Installed and set environment  **CMake**
- Installed **OpenCV 4.5.2**
- OpenCV **Makefile generation**

  - using CMake **Build** from **source**(openCV directory)
- specified the generator for the project

  - configured the compiler type and makefile type
- Enabled precompiled header

**Confusing part**

- when I entered the command `mingw32-make` for compilation in directory where the makefile is generated
- It worked until 67% after that:

```sh
 [ 67%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_test_dnn
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_test_dnn
[ 67%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_dnn.dir/test/npy_blob.cpp.obj
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
D:/opencv/build/modules/dnn/test_precomp.hpp:50:10: fatal error: test_common.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "test_common.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules\dnn\CMakeFiles\opencv_test_dnn.dir\build.make:82: modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_dnn.dir/test/npy_blob.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:3429: modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_dnn.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:181: all] Error 2
```

thank you

Comment: You may have to do some investigation into this before expecting to get help. What I mean is you are probably doing the correct steps. You may have something in CMake enabled that does not work with the settings that you selected.

Comment: Your first step is to figure out where `test_common.hpp` is located. Is that in the same folder as `D:/opencv/build/modules/dnn/test_precomp.hpp` or some other folder.

Comment: @drescherjm I solved it... this feels so good (without any help) Solution I just disabled the ALLOCATOR during compiling and some little configuration ....

Comment: You may want to write an answer if you can explain your steps.